# What does each ComboBox.Selected... return?

Tags: c#, .net, string, combobox

Right now, to be sure I am getting what I want I am using

```
actionComboBox.Items[actionComboBox.SelectedIndex].ToString()
```

to retrieve the string that is stored as an item in my `TextBox`

Does one of the Selected properties return my above statement? I can never seem to get what  I want when I use those.

Like, does `actionComboBox.SelectedItem as string` return the above value?

EDIT:

I guess the true question here is: What do each Selected Property return such as; `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue`, `SelectedText`.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe : If you read the above, I always seem to have trouble with these and they break my code, so, I haven't tried changing any of them in my current project.

Comment: How are the items being loaded into the combo box? That affects the return values of those properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `SelectedText` returns the text that is selected if you are able to edit the text in the combo box. I don't think you use this property if you have the `DropDownList` style selected where the user cannot just type values into the combobox.

`SelectedValue` only applies if you are bind to a datasource. `SelectedValue` will return the item in the datasource you've selected, or if you have the `DisplayMember` field filled in, the value of the property/column that you have specified.

`SelectedItem` will return the selected item if you have just filled in the list items through the designer.

I get burned on these all the time, cause I always forget. The big question in your example is how are the items being populated into the combo box, that will affect the return values of these properties.

Answer (score 1):

`ComboBox.Items` is a collection of `System.Object`'s, so it can be anything. By default the `ComboBox` displays the return value of an object's `ToString` method. Whatever you add to the `ComboBox` will be what you will get back, though its returned as a `System.Object` and you will have to convert it back to its original type to access its members.

```
comboBox.Items.Add("foo");
```

The above will add a `System.String` to the `ComboBox`.

```
class Foo
{
    public String Bar { get; set; }
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = "Value";

comboBox.Items.Add(foo);
```

The above will add a `Foo` to the `ComboBox`. So to get your values back.

```
Object obj = comboBox.Items[comboBox.SelectedIndex];
Foo foo = obj as Foo;

if (foo != null) { // check just in case
}
```

For strings, there's no need for a conversion, calling `ToString` is fine. It's better to just use `SelectedItem` instead.

```
Foo foo = comboBox.SelectedItem as Foo;
if (foo != null) { // again, check to make sure
}
```

The power of the `ComboBox` is that since it stores a collection of `System.Object`, you can store multiple types of objects, but you are in charge of converting it back to whatever usable type it was to begin with when you need to access it.

Comment: But, what are the differences in SelectedValue, SelectedItem, SelectedText?

Comment: `SelectedValue` gets a value used when its data bound, `SelectedItem` returns `System.Object`, and `SelectedText` returns the text in the selectable region when its editable. Please read Msdn documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx